# 論理演算の結果を10進数で表したい

Tags: c

こちらを一つずつ、10進数で表したいのですが、ぜんぜんわかりません。
わかる方教えていただきたいです。

```
15 & 7

6 & 4

9 OR 3

5 OR 10
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちら「C」というタグがついておりますが、これは C 言語に関する質問につけるタグになります。もし C 言語とは関係なくビット演算についてのご質問ということであればタグを付け替えたいのですが、実際どうでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

問題の`9 OR 3`は`9 | 3`の10進数表現を求めているのだと考えました。
※　C言語のORのビット演算は`|`、ANDのビット演算は`&`です。

考え方は、数値を２進数に基数変換し、１ビットずつ＆(AND)や｜(OR)のビット演算を行ったあと、結果を１０進数に基数変換すればよいと思います。
答えを知りたいだけなら以下のようにprintfでビット演算結果を表示してみればよいと思います。

```
 printf("%d\n", 15&7);
```

---

【追記しました】

C言語の論理演算の演算子はANDが`&&`、ORが`||`です。
C言語は整数を真偽値として扱うことができます。
整数0の真偽値は偽、0以外の整数は真です。評価するときは1でも2でも真ですが、演算結果は1になります。
2つの整数のうちひとつでも0(偽)ならば論理演算AND(`&&`)の結果は0(偽)で、両方とも0以外のときに結果は1(真)となります。
整数が両方とも0(偽)ならば論理演算OR(`||`)の結果は0(偽)で、ひとつでも0以外のときに結果は真(1)となります。

ビット演算は1ビットずつの論理演算と考えればよいと思います。

質問に「10進数で表したい」とありましたので勝手にビット演算と考えて回答しましたが、
「論理演算」と「ビット演算」の違いを理解しておいた方がよいと思い、回答に追記しました。